# Adding by-path to /dev/disk

Tags: disk-management

I have a script relying on `/dev/disk/by-path`, but that subdirectory does not exist.  When I `ls /dev/disk`, I get:

```
by-id         by-label        by-uuid
```

How do I get `by-path`?

(Output of grep -ri 'by-path' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules is:

```
# persistent storage links: /dev/disk/{by-id,by-uuid,by-label,by-path}
# by-path (parent device path)
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}"
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-part%n"
```

)

(Output of sudo udevadm info --root --name=/dev/sdc | grep DEVTYPE is:

```
E: DEVTYPE=disk
```

)

Comment: What's your goal?

Comment: After an Android build, a script loads an SD card with the image.  In the script, a 'ls /dev/disk/by-path' output is used to populate variables.  End goal is to load the Android image, but immediate goal is to satisfy the script by creating /dev/disk/by-path.

Comment: Mount the SD Card and you have `/dev/disk/by-path`.

Comment: Mounting the SD card doesn't create it for my system.

Comment: But you can see the SD card in your filemanager?

Comment: Yes, it shows in the filemanager under Devices.  Sidenote: I noticed if I mount it on the command line, it no longer appears in the filemanager, unmount, shows again.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `grep -ri 'by-path' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules`

Comment: @JeffK, Could you mention your release?

Comment: Insert your SD card, [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo udevadm info --root  --name=/dev/sdc | grep DEVTYPE`. Replace `/dev/sdc` with your drive.

Comment: And give me a ping in the comments via @A.B.

Comment: The DEVTYPE is ok, you should have a `disk/by-path` if you plug the stick.

Comment: And the output of `sudo udevadm info --root --name=/dev/sdc | grep ID_PATH=`, i hope `/dev/sdc` is the correct device.

Comment: @JeffK , please add output of `sudo udevadm test --name=/dev/sdc` this is for debuging

Answer (score 1):

The path `/dev/disk/by-path` is automatically created when you add the SD card to your system (not via `mount`). Responsible for this is `udev` and the rules in

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
```

With a simple command you can see the rules:

```
% grep -ri 'by-path' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
# persistent storage links: /dev/disk/{by-id,by-uuid,by-label,by-path}
# by-path (parent device path)
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}"
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-part%n"
```

---

And you should not use `ls /dev/disk/by-path` to get the values for your variables. Use

```
for f in /dev/disk/by-path/*; do echo "$f"; done
```

instead.

Comment: Oddly enough, it doesn't create by-path automatically for my system, whether mounted on the command line or by the GUI file explorer window.  I'm guessing my system has a quirk that is making it different, but I'm unsure how to track it down.  Open to other ideas.